# How to scrape data from Twitter from multiple URLs in a column of Excel

Tags: vba, excel, scrape

I need to basically **fill two cells in each row with data from the respective URL** present in the same row. When the query is made using macro it returns 5 pieces of data out of which I need only two.

I recorded two macros(one to query the page and other to adjust the data pieces i get) and combined them and applied a do while loop.

But it is **returning an error** in this line -  `myurl = "URL;" & Tabsheet.Cells(i, 6)`

Below is the code:

```
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

Sheets("Tabsheet").Select
Range("A1").Select
Dim i As Integer, myurl As String
i = 1
Do While i < 102
    myurl = "URL;" & Tabsheet.Cells(i, 6)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        myurl, Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(i, 8))
        .Name = "Query" & i
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "3"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    Range("H105").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("I104").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("I103").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("H102").Select

    i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Any suggestions will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
myurl = CStr("URL;" & Sheets("Tabsheet").Cells(i, 6))
```

You can use TabSheet directly as you didn't set it as an object, you could have if you did that before :

```
Dim TabSheet As Worksheet

Set TabSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TabSheet")

'------------------------------------
'--------Here come your code---------
'------------------------------------


'And when it's done, don't forget to free what you have set
Set TabSheet = Nothing
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much, but now i have another error I can't make sense of -
It says, "The address of this site is not valid" and highlights this line  -
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False .

Comment: **When you have an error**, please **specify on which line** (you can use back tiles like this one  ` to embeded code in a wrote line here on StackExchange) **and which error message** did you get.